# Extracting the numbers out of a SymPy expression

Tags: python, sympy

How can I extract all the numerical values from a SymPy expression?
For example, for this expression: `sin(a/pi + a) + 0.629116159212`, I want `pi`, `-1`, and `0.629116159212`.

I found the `srepr` function in SymPy, which returns for the example:

```
Add(sin(Add(Mul(Pow(pi, Integer(-1)), Symbol('a')), Symbol('a'))), Float('0.62911615921200004', precision=53))
```

How can I extract all the numbers from this, i.e., everything that is not a `Symbol`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The method `atoms` returns a set of all atomic (i.e., unsplittable) components of an expression.
- The attribute `is_number` tells you whether some expression (or atom) is a number.

Combined:

```
from sympy import sin, pi
from sympy.abc import a

expr = sin(a/pi + a) + 0.629116159212
numbers = {atom for atom in expr.atoms() if atom.is_number}
```

---

Now, if you need to **preserve the count** of appearances, things get a bit more complicated, since `atoms` returns a set.
Here, we additionally can use:

- Alternative 1:
  `sympy.preorder_traversal` (or `postorder_traversal`) which iterates through all subexpressions of an expression.
  (Thanks to [Oscar Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922148/extracting-the-numbers-out-of-a-sympy-expression/59922456?noredirect=1#comment105969106_59922456) and [A.S. Meurer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922148/extracting-the-numbers-out-of-a-sympy-expression/59922456?noredirect=1#comment105975561_59922456).)
- Alternative2:
  The method `find` of expressions, which returns all expressions matching some criterion.
- The attribute `is_Atom`.

```
from sympy import sin, pi, preorder_traversal
from sympy.abc import a

expr = sin(a/pi + 1/a) + 0.629116159212

is_atomic_number = lambda expr: expr.is_Atom and expr.is_number

# Alternative 1:
[
    subexpression
    for subexpression in preorder_traversal(expr)
    if is_atomic_number(subexpression)
]

# Alternative 2:
expr.find(is_atomic_number,group=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It's almost what I need. The only problem is that it seems that this doesn't return duplicates i.e. if I have expr = sin(a/pi + 1/a) + 0.629116159212 (I changed a to 1/a), this return the number -1 only once, even if it appears 2 times and I need it 2 times for my code. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You can use `expr.find(lambda e: e.is_Number, group=True)` to get numbers and counts.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin thanks a lot! But it seems to not work with pi

Comment: @BillKet use `is_number` (lowercase) to get all numbers including symbolic ones.

Comment: @asmeurer I tried it, but it is not working. For this: expr = sin(a/pi + 1/a) + pi, when I use is_Number I get: {-1: 2}, when I use is_number I get: {pi: 2, -1: 2, 1/pi: 1}, none of which is what I need. What I would need here is: {pi: 2, -1: 2}. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you want to check for `NumberSymbol` instances (the superclass of `pi`).

Comment: @BillKet: *Is there a way to fix this?* – See my edit.